# Angular4 Components inheritance with abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, components, abstract

I want to define a base class for my components to share some features. So i've began with :

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
    protected getName(): string;
}

@Component(...)
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent {
    protected getName(): string {
        return "MyComponent";
    }
}
```

But after i needed to add some annotations to BaseComponent like `@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])`. So i had to add `@Component` to `BaseComponent` to enable angular annotations. Everything was good... Until i tried to compile in production mode with

> ng build --prod

:

> Cannot determine the module for class BaseComponent

So i've added `BaseComponent` to `@NgModule`, but i had :

> No template specified for component BaseComponent

So i've added

```
@Component({template: ''})
```

But i had :

> Argument of type 'typeof BaseComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type'. Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.

So i had remove the "`abstract`" keyword to compile in production mode my project.

Do you have a solution? **I dislike bad conception!**

Comment: Did you try just to add the HostListener without doing anything else ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

### Update for Angular 10+

As of Angular 10, when using the IVY compiler, components that are inherited, and which contain Angular functionality, must be decorated with an empty `@Directive()` decorator.

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes)

---

There's no need to add `@Component()` annotations to abstract classes or register them to any module.

It could be that there's something wrong within your code that does not conform to what Angular expects.

I created a demo application using Angular CLI 1.2.7 with the `ng new <name>` command and extend the AppComponent class as below.

**`base.component.ts`**

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class BaseComponent {
    @HostListener('click')
    onClick() {
        alert('Click');
    }
}
```

and

**`app.component.ts`**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BaseComponent } from './base.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent extends BaseComponent {
    title = 'app';
}
```

The app.module class was not changed in any way.

The click handler located in the base component worked without any problems. A AOT compilation using `ng build --prod` also did not give any errors.

This demo was using angular v5.1.1

Comment: O_o I don't understand, yesterday that's not works... Ok, fine, it's perfect!

Comment: The thing is that in case the abstract class is extending another class which is a component, then Angular will require to declare the class in a module, which will subsequently fail since you cannot declare abstract classes in Angular. :(

Comment: @CaptainFogetti then there is any solution to over come?

Comment: @k11k2 there is not any that I am aware of. In the end I had to reorganize my code so that there is no Angular component in the parent hierarchy of the abstract class. Sadly Angular has it's shortcomings too :(

Comment: @Walfrat you don't understand the discussion. There is no concrete component to inherit from. We are talking about an abstract superclass which cannot be annotated with the `@Component` annotation. And yes. Angular 4 smells sometimes, I'll give you that. But still it's a great framework despite it's shortcomings.

Comment: It's great. But we should always use Directives for all these functionalities. Abstract class inheritance is good when we want to restrict component to implement/extends few methods/properties.

Comment: Can you create tests for a class like this?

Comment: +10 for the @Component decorator being unnecessary! Thanks!

Comment: Another related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126097/1589218