# Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some components like `CricketComponent`, `FootballComponent`, `TennisComponent` etc. All These Classes have some common properties :- `TeamName, teamSize, players` etc which are `@Input()`.

Now I created a `BaseComponent` class, defined all these properties in there and this `baseComponent` class will be extended by cricket/football/tennis/etcComponents.

baseComponent.ts

```
export class BaseComponent {

    @Input() TeamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;

}
```

CricketComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cricket',
  templateUrl: './cricket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cricket.component.scss']
})
export class cricketComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

I am getting this error:

ERROR in src/app/base-screen.ts:4:14 - error NG2007:

**Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.**

Comment: export abstract class BaseComponent {

    @Input() TeamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;

} - try to add abstract

Comment: I am not using any abstract class I have just created new component but i am getting 
"Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)"

Could you please guide me on above

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You'll need to add a `@Component` decorator to that base class (which should probably also be declared `abstract`).

This is the bare minimum you can get away with in Angular 9:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: ''
})
export abstract class BaseComponent {

    @Input() teamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;
}
```

For Angular 10+, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964736/3558960).

Comment: I have done the same before asking the question and Error got resolved. But is it right to use template: 'EMPTYQUOTESHERE'.

Comment: I mean, It felts like a hack. BaseComponent is not an angular component. It is just a typescript Class which gets extended by other ANGULAR COMPONENTS.

Comment: Can you confirm on this ?

Comment: I know it feels hacky, but for me this is the way I got it to work in Angular 9. I'm not aware of other options at the moment... Maybe a `Directive` would work...

Comment: I am marking this answer is correct. Meanwhile, I dig into the angular Docs to find if there can be a better approach. I also encourage you to do the same.

Comment: Actually, for Angular10+ use `@Directive()` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823687/776345))

Answer (score 108):

From Angular 10, you can fix this issue by adding the decorator @Injectable() to your abstract base class like this:

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseComponent {    
    @Input() teamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;
}
```

Comment: I seem to get build errors with this solution when my extending component has an attribute selector, like `li[ng-list-item]`. I get something like `Attribute "teamName" does not exist on li`. Using Directive worked.

Comment: This is the only solution which worked for me!

Comment: This is a big one for Angular 10 as they changed how strict the compiler is for classes without decorators https://angular.io/guide/migration-injectable

Comment: This was making `@Input()`s defined by my base class `undefined`. I had to switch to `@Directive()` instead. This is what I see in Angular 11 at least, not sure about others.

Comment: The correct annotation is `@Directive()`. See https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes or the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68823687/318317

Comment: : Cannot find name 'Injectable'.

Comment: @SaigeZhang it'll be `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: I am not using any abstract class I have just created new component but i am getting "Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)" Could you please guide me on above –

Comment: if you need lifecycle hooks in this class then you will see lint errors with @Injectable

Comment: The Angular migration documentation for this is now found at https://v10.angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes

Answer (score 41):

While the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126097/4591974) is correct in using `@Component`, one minor downside is that it requires all constructor argument types to be resolvable by DI.  So if your base class constructor takes a constant/literal - say, an enum - as a flag, you're going to have to set up a corresponding DI provider/token just to get it to compile.

You can however also resolve NG2007 using the `@Directive` decorator instead, which doesn't require DI compatibility

Comment: The `@Directive` decorator is what Angular's schematics (ie. [`ng update`](https://angular.io/cli/update)) will automatically add

Answer (score 26):

**See also:** [Missing @Directive()/@Component() decorator migration](https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes)

**Before:**

```
export class BaseComponent {
    @Input() TeamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;
}
```

**After:**

```
@Directive()
export class BaseComponent {
    @Input() TeamName: string;
    @Input() teamSize: number;
    @Input() players: any;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `@Injectable()` decorator to your class, and you can import it from the following path, `import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing this in Angular 15, use an exact version of TypeScript. 4.8.2 worked for me.

```
npm i typescript@4.8.2 -D --save-exact
```

Comment: I did same but error still happening, what editor do you use ?
I use neovim

Comment: @ValDo I use VSCode, which version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation when running `ng serve`. I was getting that error for 3rd party libraries and for all my Angular components even though they were decorated.

If you're having this problem, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69471784/6841414) for [Angular 11 'error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated.' But the class is Decorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065880/angular-11-error-ng2007-class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated)

Answer (score 0):

For These errors :
NG6001: The class 'XComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'A' of class 'Y'.

NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.

You may be writing the new class between @Component declaration and Component class.

ex.

// export class Y{
// }

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-X',
  templateUrl: './X.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./X.component.css']
})



export class XComponent implements OnInit {

todos : Y[]  = [
  new Y(1 ),
  new Y(2 ),
  new Y(3 )
]
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

//export class Y{
//}

i.e. if you have more than one class . let say class XComponent and Class Y, where class Y is being used in class XComponent , then write code for class Y either above @Component({}) or below class XComponent