# HTML errors appearing on .ts file in vscode

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this issue where certain .ts files are lined with errors you'd expect to see in an HTML file, e.g. "Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'" appears over an import in my component [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoBA5.png)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled vs code to no avail.

Comment: Try to use `f1` then type `reload window` to reload the VSCode window

Comment: No luck, the errors just return - thanks anyways

Comment: I need more details if you may. And of course you're welcome anytime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused by extending another component that didn't have angular decorations. Fixing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126067/class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated-please-add-an-explicit-ang) resolved the errors.