# Angular Component inheritance without a template in base class

Tags: angularjs, typescript, inheritance, angular-components, base-class

I need to create a base class which consists of common logic and to Inherit it and create multiple components.
While checking in the internet I found two ways of doing that.

1. Use base class as a Pure typescript class and use @component decorator in inherited components.
2. Use base class with @component with empty template and use @component in inherited components too.

It's appreciated if you can illustrate the correct way of achieving this.

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64964736/3558960)? Does that not work for you?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of achieving this depending on your use case. For simplicity, you can just create a base component class with a constructor and provide the dependencies from the inheriting or subclass via the super call e.g

```
export class BaseComponent {
    constructor(modal: ModalService) {
    }
    
    /*
        Implement code and logic common to inheriting components
     */
}
```

You can now extend this class from your component by injecting the modal service into the child class on passing onto the base class

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseComponent} from './base.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(modal: ModalService) {
        super(modal)
    }
}
```

You can annotate your base component with the `@Component` angular decorator with an empty template to make your base component life cycle aware

Comment: Thanks ! Pretty useful to manage all rxjs and pipes ;)