# Class is using Angular features but is not decorated with Typescript 4.8.2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this "Class is using Angular features but is not decorated" error on all my components on Angular since I upgraded Typescript to 4.8.2.

This error shows on the export class name of each component.

Has anyone expericenced this same issue ?

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-members",
  templateUrl: "./members.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./members.component.scss"]
})
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {...
```

In this example the "MembersComponent" throws the error.

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2021.String",
      "ES2021",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the version of Angular's typescript.

Comment: add this line at the top - import { Component} from  '@angular/core';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 11 'error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated.' But the class is Decorated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065880/angular-11-error-ng2007-class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, the code still compiles and runs ok, but for now I have downgraded typescript to 4.7.4, ro prevent annoying errors in editor .. and also keeping an eye out for next version higher than 4.8.2 to see if any fix