# Class is using Angular features but is not decorated in angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

I have updated my angular app from 13 to 14.  After update i am getting below error
after opening component class in vs code.

> Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an
> explicit Angular decorator

I have checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065880/angular-11-error-ng2007-class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated/69471784#69471784)

But i have not using any ineritance in the app.

[image]

But the application run perfectly. How to remove that error?

ts.confing

/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "strict": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true, 
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2022",
    "lib": [
      "es2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "stream": [ "./node_modules/stream-browserify" ]
    },
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": false,
  }
}
```

Validation component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ValidationService } from 'src/app/core/services/validation.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-validation-message',
  template: '<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null" style="width:50%;margin-top:.25rem;font-size:80%;color:#dc3545">{{errorMessage}}</div>'
})

export class ValidationMessageComponent {
  @Input() control: AbstractControl;

  constructor() {
  }

  get errorMessage() {
    if (this.control.errors) {
    
      for (let propertyName in this.control.errors) {
        if (this.control.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && this.control.touched) {
          return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName, this.control.errors[propertyName]);
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: check the vscode's ts version

Comment: See my question ( And the solution iv'e found) [I degraded typescript ver.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73547718/how-do-i-implement-oninit-without-getting-error-class-is-using-angular-features/73548216?noredirect=1#comment129879176_73548216)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem, i resolve it by downgrading typescript dependencies:

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
"typescript": "4.7.2"
```

now the error is gone and all is working perfectly

Comment: Yes i have downgraded typescript..Thanks

Comment: You may also want to restart your IDE once TS is downgraded

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue. Typescript downgrade from 4.7.4 to 4.7.2 resolved the problem.

`npm i typescript@4.7.2`

Answer (score 7):

it is due to Angular Language Service extension, it does not support Typescript `4.8` yet, see related issue here:
https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/1746

Edit: issue is now closed extension is now updated, so downgrade is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Angular 15. This time upgrading typescript from 4.8.2 to 4.8.4 solved the problem.

Comment: I have typescript 4.8.4 and still have this issue. Did you do something in particular to fix it ?

Comment: Nothing else. Well, first I downgraded ts to 4.7.2, but Angular didn't like it so I re-installed and ended up with 4.8.4 working.

Comment: It didn't fix the issue for me. Downgrading did. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

initially i had typescript 4.8.4 when hitting this problem.
after i read through here, I downgraded to 4.7.2, didn't work; then I went back to 4.8.4, interestingly it worked.