# How do I implement OnInit without getting error: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator

Tags: angular, typescript-decorator, ngoninit, angular-decorator

I would like to get rid of the Error above.
It started to appear after re-installed dependencies using npm i.

I tried removing "implements onInit" and it disappeared So the problem is related to it.
But I want to use "implements onInit" without getting this error.
I suspect it has to do also with typescript version (Which i upgraded to the latest).

Update: Of course I implemented ngOnInit function inside the class.

Error Message:

> Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.(-992007)?

Code:

```
export class SomeClass implements OnInit {
ngOnInit():void{ 
//some code};
}
```

Comment: Just revert the Typescript version to what it was maybe?

Comment: when u have implements onInit u must have ngOnInit function declared within class or it will error

Comment: I edited my question. I have ngOnInit() inside the class I just forgot to mention it. I want to use the latest ts version otherwise what's the point to be with lower version instead of fizong the problem?

Answer (score 2):

This error happened after updating typescript to latest.
What I did is to rollback
command

> npm i typescript@4.7.2

And it was fixed.

Comment: Good answer but "npm i typescript@4.7.2 -D" is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

From angular 13 you will be getting this error I guess, if you are using angular features you need a decorator for it, you can simply add a dummy decorator for this and solve your issue!

```
@Directive()
export class TestClass {

}
```

implements just enforces that `ngOnInit` needs to be present inside the class, there is no use for it outside of an angular component!

Comment: Adding @Directive didn't work for me. But I removed the "Implements" .. as a second thought I really don't see in this type of component a point to do so. Thank you for helping

Comment: @UriGross You can also change the class to abstract class maybe that is an alternative, anyway good that its fixed!