# Q: Angular components broken - "Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator"

Tags: angular, typescript

After many hours of trying to find a solution, I have come up short. Without fail, every time I generate a new component in my Angular app it is the same message. "Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator"

Below are some of my components and their decorators.

[image: Component 1]

[image]

And even a test component fresh out of the CLI for good measure.

[image]

I know I can get rid of the problem by removing OnInit implementation. But in other components I do need it.

Things I have tried

delete node_modules, reinstall and downgrade and upgrade TypeScript version from 4.7.2 to 4.8.2 then to 4.7.2 again.

TS Config

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.1.0",
    "daisyui": "^2.24.0",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.16",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  }
```

I also appear to have lost auto-complete for adding components in the html file. E.g. in app module - no dropdown after typing <app-...>. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check the import of component decorator, is it `import {component} from '@angular/core'` also please try to replicate the issue in a stackblitz, please check if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065880/angular-11-error-ng2007-class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated) helps!

Comment: I had a look at that thread, the solutions there did not work for me. I cannot replicate it in a stackblitz nor by generating a new angular app.

Comment: @tudo14 what about the first option? have you tried it?

Comment: Yes @NarenMurali

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126067/class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated-please-add-an-explicit-ang)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my folder structure (atleast I believe).

I had node modules of my server and ts config in the root of my folder, and then my client app as a folder in the root too.

The solution was to move EVERYTHING related to server into its own folder, no node modules or ts config.

reponame, client and server folders. not client and server folders, with server tsconfig and node modules in root.

Comment: can you clarify what reponame, client and server folders. not client and server folders, with server tsconfig and node modules in root. does it mean ? , how it looks at the end ? can you provide a picture ?