# How to pass arguments from derived component class to base class

Tags: angular

I am upgrading from Angular 7 to Angular 12.

I have a number of component which all derive from a common base class, where I pass in some constructor arguments.

**Base Component**

```
export abstract class PageBase implements OnDestroy{
    constructor(
            moduleName: string,
            protected logger: Logger,    
        ) {
    }
```

**Derived Component**

```
const moduleName = 'MyPageComponent';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-page',
    templateUrl: './mypage.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mypage.component.scss']
})
export class MyPageComponent extends PageBase implements OnInit { 
constructor(
    logger: Logger,    
    protected actions$: Actions,
    ) {
    super(moduleName, logger); // <-- pass arg to base class
```

When building after the upgrade, I get the following error

```
Error: src/app/shared/page-base.ts:12:23 - error NG2007: Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.
12 export abstract class PageBase implements OnDestroy{
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126067/class-is-using-angular-features-but-is-not-decorated-please-add-an-explicit-ang), I have added the `@Component({template: ''})`, so I now have

```
@Component({template: ''})
export abstract class PageBase implements OnDestroy{
```

But now I get a error complaining about the string I pass in from each derived class

```
    Error: src/app/shared/page-base.ts:24:5 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'moduleName' of class 'PageBase'.
        Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

    24     moduleName: string,
                 ~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I remove the `ngOnDestroy` from the base class, I can then remove the `@Component({template: ''})`, and it all builds again.

But I was using `ngOnDestroy` to do common cleanup for all derived classes (eg common rgrx subscriptions).

What do I need to do here to still be able to have `ngOnDestroy` in the base class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angular takes over the constructor() function with the injector. You may use an abstract property.:

abstract component PageBase

```
export abstract class PageBase implements OnDestroy{

abstract moduleName: string;

constructor(protected logger: Logger) {}

ngOnDestroy() {
 console.log(this.moduleName);
```

}

MyPageComponent

```
export class MyPageComponent extends PageBase implements OnInit { 

moduleName = 'MyPageComponent';

constructor(logger: Logger,    
   protected actions$: Actions) {

   super(logger); // <-- pass arg to base class
}
```

Comment: I see, know now for the future, Yes the above will suite my purposes fine. Thankyou