# Template type checks errors after migration to angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I am gettings errors everywhere after I migrated to angular 12 from angular 8.
By the way I did not get any error when migrating from 8 to 9, neither from 9 to 10, nor from 10 to 11.

Here is an example of error I get:

```
export interface HistoriqueStatutModel {
  userId: string;
  date: Date;
  statutCible: string;
  commentaire?: string;
  montantFacture?: number;
}

export interface CommentaireModel {
  message: string;
  date: Date;
  createdBy: string;
}

--- 

public listeStatut: Array<HistoriqueStatutModel | CommentaireModel>;

---

 <li *ngFor="let statut of listeStatut;">
    {{statut.message}}
 </li>
```

I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'HistoriqueStatutModel | CommentaireModel'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type 'HistoriqueStatutModel'.
 {{statut.message}}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you tried using "?" while accessing property "message"? I mean {{statut?.message}}

Comment: yes I already tried this of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 12 was the first version that had [template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) set to `strict` by default, that's why you're only now seeing these errors.

You can turn this off in your TypeScript configuration file by setting the [`strictTemplates`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates) flag to false.

Of course, it would be better to perform proper type checking in your code instead.

Comment: I was looking for that. You saved my day

Comment: what about this error: ` Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.` 
How to solve it  without adding explicit decorator ?

Comment: I get your answer here ^^ 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63126097/6717287

Comment: related issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75483383/angular-13-routing-static-with-resolved-data-does-not-work