# Angular 13 routing: Static with Resolved Data does not work

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

After migration to angular 13, I get this routing errors:

error TS2339: Property 'myParam' does not exist on type 'Data'.

```
 this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ myParam, operation }) => {
  const myVariable = myParam; // this does not work 
})
```

---

```
{
    path: ':id/delete',
    component: MyComponentDeletePopupComponent,
    resolve: {
      myParam: MyComponentResolve
    },
    data: {
      authorities: ['...'],
      pageTitle: 'home.title',
      operation: 'DELETE'
    },
    canActivate: [UserRouteAccessService],
    outlet: 'popup'
  }
```

---

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use  `res['myParam']` and `res['operation']`

It should look like this:

```
this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(res => {
  const myAttribute = res['myParam'];
});
```