Angular 18 abstract component with new input / output
I would like to create an abstract class that some components inherit. I am using Angular 18 output() from @angular/core. I can't do that with a simple abstract class because the new output() function complains to be outside an Angular component :
import { output } from '@angular/core';

export abstract class AbstractGeneralCardComponent {
  seeMoreClick = output<void>();
  seeLessClick = output<void>();
}

Unsupported call to the output function. This function can only be used as the initializer 
of a property on a @Component or @Directive class.

How to achieve this ?

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63126067 with a slightly different error message.
